# Connect two esxi hosts via nics for private networking for vm's to communicate without switch/router

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have 2 hosts, ESXi01 and ESXi02 with 2 nics each. 1 nic on each is connected to 10.0.0.0 network, nic 2 on both hosts are connected to each other (server to server).

I've setup switch01 using nic 1, switch02 using nic 2 on each host.

1 VM in each host with 2 nics inside the vm's. 1st one on switch01 and 2nd one on switch02.

I've assigned static IP's:

**VM1 on Host-01**

**NIC1 :** 10.0.0.20

SUBNET: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 10.0.0.1

**NIC2:** 172.16.0.1

SUBNET: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: Blank

**VM2 on Host-02**

**NIC1:** 10.0.0.21

SUBNET: 255.255.255.0

GATEWAY: 10.0.0.1

**NIC2:** 172.16.0.21

SUBNET: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: blank

I can't get VM1 to ping to VM2 via ping 172.16.0.21. Is there something more that needs to be done on the esxi side? or do I set the gateway to the VM itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network configuration looks okay (you don't need a gateway configured on NIC2, and it probably would be more challenging if you had one).

Are you sure your network cable between the servers is a crossover cable instead of a standard patch cable?  If it is not, and if the servers don't support automatically adjusting, then they won't be able to communicate.

Another approach (if you have a spare physical switch) is to connect the spare switch between the two servers.